# How to check if a file exists in javascript?

Tags: jquery, file, exists

I'm using the jquery library to load the content of an html file. Something like this:

$("#Main").load("login.html")

If the file (in this case 'login.html') does not exist, I would like to detect it so that I can redirect the user to an error page for example. Any ideas how I can detect if the file to load exists or not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the ajaxComplete event, whis gives you access to the xhr object which you can query the status of the request e.g a status of 404 will mean the file does not exist.

More Info in the docs http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/ajaxComplete#callback

Test here http://pastebin.me/48f32a74927bb

e.g

```
$("#someDivId").ajaxComplete(function(request, settings){
    if (settings.status===404){
        //redirect here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

@PConroy's solution works, but it does the same thing for all failed ajax requests.

If you need this on a per request basis - i.e. if the first request fails it goes to X page and if the second fails go to Y, then you need to do this using the error handle in the $.ajax function:

http://jsbin.com/iwume

(to edit: http://jsbin.com/iwume/edit)

Comment: You should show the basics of the solution here instead of requiring people to click on a link. Links are fine for providing additional information, but there should be enough information in the answer itself.