# jQuery if exist

Tags: jquery, file

How to check, is file exist on current site?

Like:

```
if ('http://site.com/girlfirend.png' exist) {
// do something
}
```

Maybe I can use `.get`? But how to check its status (ok or 404)?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a file exists in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197228/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-javascript)

Comment: @Piskvor - they are using div for load. I have just url to check

Comment: What you *do* with the content doesn't really matter - whether you put it into a DIV or throw it away. The thing both you and the other question are interested in is the response.status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue a get request to the file and inspect the result.

See [**Ajax in jquery**](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

Comment: You can do such a request with ajax, and specify you only want the HEAD (in order to check the response code).

Comment: Check this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197228/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-javascript

Comment: @greg0ire, quoth jQuery docs: "The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers."

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery, this has been asked here:

[How to check if a file exists in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197228/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-javascript)

Comment: I have to check without $("#someDivId")